# How to use $query, $hint or $explain from Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB 3.4
My methods are:-

```
MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase(mongoDBLogs);
MongoIterable<String> allCollections = db.listCollectionNames();
str==FROM COLLECTION
MongoCollection<Document> table = db.getCollection(str);
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = table.find(queryForLogs).iterator();
```

The problem is in OLD version I can use the

```
DB db = mongo.getDB(mongoDBLogs);
Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();
for (String s : colls) {
DBCollection table = db.getCollection(s);
cursor = table.find().explain(); <<<<---- I have this explain method
AND ALSO I have
cursor = table.find().hint(indexKeys);<<<<---- I have this hint method
}
```

NOW in 3.4 I am not able to access these options by using

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = table.find(queryForLogs).explain() <-- this is type  FindIterable<Document>
```

OR

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = table.find(queryForLogs).hint(Some value); <---This is type  FindIterable<Document>
```

I refer the link:-
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

So I make another method:-

```
    public  BasicDBObject generateQueryForSessionIDLogs(String service_name, String node_name, Date gtDate, Date lteDate, String session_id,List<String> logLevel, String errorMsg){
        BasicDBObject andQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        List<BasicDBObject> obj = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

        //Use session to search. If session is unknown, start and end date must be provided
        if(!session_id.isEmpty() && session_id != null){
            String[] sessionarray = session_id.split(",");

            if(sessionarray.length == 1){
                Long val = Long.valueOf(sessionarray[0].trim()).longValue();
                obj.add(new BasicDBObject("s", val));

            } else{ 
                ArrayList<Long> vals =  new ArrayList<Long>();
                for(String strn : sessionarray){
                    vals.add(Long.valueOf(strn.trim()).longValue());
                }

                obj.add(new BasicDBObject("s", new BasicDBObject("$in", vals )));
            }
        }else{      
            if((gtDate != null) && (lteDate != null)){
                obj.add(new BasicDBObject("d",  new BasicDBObject("$gt", gtDate).append("$lte", lteDate)));
            }
        }

        if(!node_name.isEmpty()){
            obj.add(new BasicDBObject("i", node_name));
        }
        if(!service_name.isEmpty()){
            obj.add(new BasicDBObject("n", service_name ));
        }
        if(!errorMsg.isEmpty()) {
            obj.add(new BasicDBObject("m", Pattern.compile(errorMsg)));
        }

        if(!logLevel.isEmpty()){
//          obj.add(new BasicDBObject("r", new BasicDBObject("$in", logLevel )));
            obj.add(new BasicDBObject("r", logLevel.get(0) ));
        }

        if (obj.size() > 1){ //append 'AND' if there is >1 conditions
            andQuery.put("$and", obj);
        }

        BasicDBObject andQuery2 = new BasicDBObject();
        andQuery2.put("$query", andQuery);
        List<BasicDBObject> obj2 = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
        obj2.add(new BasicDBObject("i",1));
        andQuery2.put("$hint", obj2);
        andQuery2.put("$explain", 1);
        logger.debug("Query String for Logs: " + andQuery2);
        return andQuery;
    }
```

**My final query make like:-**

***`Query String for Logs: { "$query" : { "$and" : [ { "d" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2017-06-19T04:00:00.000Z"} , "$lte" : { "$date" : "2017-06-20T04:00:00.000Z"}}} , { "i" : "WM96BEPSIT02"}]} , "$hint" : [ { "i" : 1}] , "$explain" : 1}`***

**With error:-**
*`Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-16" Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-15" com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'unknown top level operator: $query' on server`*

Please also suggest any alternative way to call the indexed values first. As in my case all search values are not indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send things like `$hint` or `$explain` to the Java driver you actually use the [`.modifiers()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/async/client/FindIterable.html) method from [`FindIterable`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/async/client/FindIterable.html). For instance:

```
MongoCursor<Document> iterator = collection.find()
    .modifiers(new Document("$explain",1)).iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(iterator.next().toJson());
}
```

This will print the explain stats output.

Any [`BsonDocument`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/org/bson/BsonDocument.html) type is valid to provide as an argument.
The valid list is on [Query Modifiers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-modifier/) in the core documentation.

Generally speaking, `$query` is not something that you actually use from the modifiers list, since you are actually constructing that with any argument to `.find()`. But all the other modifiers are valid for use here.