# Retrieve fields of all documents in mongodb collection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to retrieve all Fields of all Documents and embeded Documents in Mongo collection.
this is an example of one document:

```
{
   "_id": {
      "$oid": "53b309def468718462e0c390"
   },
   "customer": {
      "companyName": "Vins et alcools Chevalier",
      "contactName": "Paul Henriot",
   },
   "employee": {
      "employeeId": 5,
      "firstName": "Steven",
      "lastName": "Buchanan"
   },
   "orderItems": [
      {
         "productName": "Queso Cabrales",
         "unitPrice": 14,
         "quantity": 12
      },
      {
         "productName": "Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee",
         "unitPrice": 9.8,
         "quantity": 10
      }
   ],
   "orderId": 10248,
   "orderDate": {
      "$date": "1996-07-04T07:00:00.000Z"
   },
   "requiredDate": {
      "$date": "1996-08-01T07:00:00.000Z"
   },
   "shippedDate": {
      "$date": "1996-07-16T07:00:00.000Z"
   },
   "shipVia": "Federal Shipping",
   "freightCost": 32.38
}
```

Here is my code and output:

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursor;
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");
cursor = collection.find().iterator();
try {
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
         //System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());
         System.out.println(cursor.next().get("key"));
    }       
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

And this is the out put :

```
null null null null null ...
```

i want only the Name part, but it's not working.

> i'm using java driver 3.12.4 with mongodb v4.2

Tank you.

Comment: try using `keySet()`. You are getting `null` because your collection don't have field named `key`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667364/how-to-use-query-hint-or-explain-from-java

Comment: thank you it working, but it return a list, and how to retreive one by one exlude _id

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void printFields(){
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor;
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("user");
    cursor = collection.find().iterator();
    try {
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            //System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : cursor.next().entrySet())
            {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not retrieve filds of embeded document, like "companyName", "contactName" of document customer.
thank you